# Delay at Windows Log On Screen

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, login

I'm getting a delay when entering my password at the log on screen in Windows 7. What I mean is that I can select the text box but pressing keys does nothing. I had this problem initially on this computer with Vista installed - when I reformatted and installed Windows 7 the problem went away - but over the weeks it is slowly coming back (the delay seems to be getting longer).

Any clues as to why this is happening and how I can fix it? It currently takes about 4-8 seconds before it will accept keyboard input.

Comment: It's a notebook, and this happens whether its coming out of hibernation or powering on.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a USB keyboard?

I can't think of any reason why the USB connection would take time to come alive, but I know there are power settings and other potential issues with USB ports.

During the time you are unable to type, are you able to do **anything** with the keyboard? Try pressing Win+U to see if the accessibility tools window comes up during the non-responsive time. If it doesn't, then it would point to being a keyboard/USB issue to me - try using a PS/2 keyboard. If that solves it, check your USB driver settings, or keep using a PS/2 keyboard.

Comment: D'oh! Just realised how old this question is - hopefully you've resolved the issue by now, but if not, hope this helps!

Comment: Nope, it's a laptop and I'm just using the regular built in keyboard. It is an old question, but I still don't have a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious if it's a memory issue.  Have you tested your memory.  Also, a lot of startup programs might do it as well, but I'm not for sure on either of these.

Comment: Well, other than being able to type, the computer is very responsive - the cursor moves fine and I can select the textbox without any delays. I don't know if it would be related to startup programs as I haven't installed much past what I installed initially after formatting. I'll look in to the memory thing.